# JavaScript parent.document.getelementbyid.src/.click does not work in mobile Safari (iOS) / Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

I've made an web app which is working in chrome / safari on mac. But on my iPhone (Safari) and in the android emulator (Android-webbrowser), some javascripts are not working.

First script: (iframe and a href)

```
parent.document.getElementById('searchframe').src = 'search.php?q=' + NAME + '&maxResults=25';
parent.document.getElementById('gotosearchframe').click()
```

Second script: (iframe and a href)

```
parent.document.getElementById('player').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1';
parent.document.getElementById('dllink').href = 'http://YouTubeInMP3.com/fetch/?video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + URL;
```

When I run the scripts, nothing happens.
Maybe you have an idee?

Comment: Just use `top.document` instead

Comment: @adeneo, also that doesn`t work, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"